# How to switch the highlight color to yellow for text that will be typed in Word 2007?

Tags: vba, formatting, ms-word, office-2007

In a VBA-Macro in MS Word 2007 I want switch the text highlight color to yellow for the text that will be typed next at the cursor position.

If I want to change the color of the currently selected text, I can do that with 
`Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow`

But that only seems to work if the text already exists and is selected.
Can I also set the highlight color to yellow for the text that will be inserted at the cursor position?

(E. g. if I click on the "bold font" button, all future text will be bold,
but that does not seem to work with the highlight function, or is there a way to do it?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> all future text will be bold

No, it won't. By clicking `bold` you mark the current point in the text as bold, and if you carry on typing from that point, the text will be bold because it is being typed from a bold place, not because the button is pressed. If you click `bold`, move the caret to some other place and type, it won't be bold.

The correct way is to insert the text and apply formatting to its range.

```
Dim r As Range
Set r = Selection.Range

r.Collapse wdCollapseStart
r.InsertAfter "Text to insert"
r.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
```